# Problem with Prolog list recursion keeps returning syntax error operator expected

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

```
findSqr([],[]).
findSqr([X|Y],[SX|SY]) :-
        number(X)
        SX is X * X,
        findSqr(X,SX).
findSqr([X|Y],[X|SY]) :-
        \+number(X),
        findSqr(Y,SY).
```

Its suppose to return the elements of a list which when squared, are less than 100.

example

```
findSqr(X,[23,9,67,12,222,19,6]).

X = 9 Y = 81 ;
X = 6 Y = 36 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're currently missing a comma at the end of the `number(X)` line. That's causing the operator expected syntax error.

Nonetheless, your code still doesn't do what you want it to.

You don't have a test for values less than 100 and you're not building your result in the return variable.

Try this instead:

```
findSqr([],[]).
findSqr([X|Y],[X|T]) :-
        number(X),
        SX is X * X,
        SX < 100, !,
        findSqr(Y,T).
findSqr([X|Y],T) :-
        findSqr(Y,T).
```

When I run it I get this:

```
?- findSqr([23,9,67,12,222,19,6],X).
X = [9, 6].
```

9 & 6 are the only two numbers in the input list where their squares are less than 100.